# Why is sudo not accepting my sudo password?

Tags: python, bash, flask, passwords, sudo

I was using the terminal (Mac OS) for a python 3 flask module application. I needed to use sudo:

```
python3 -m venv flask
sudo easy-install virtualenv
```

Sudo asked me for my sudo password, and I put it in. Here's what it threw at me:

```
sorry, try again
```

[The tutorial webpage I used](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The website your are linking at says the following between these code lines:

Note that in some operating systems you may need to use python3 instead of python. The above command creates a private version of your Python interpreter inside a folder named flask.

If you are using any other version of Python older than 3.4, then you need to download and install virtualenv.py before you can create a virtual environment. If you are on Mac OS X, then you can install it with the following command.

---

It could be that you are using the wrong Python version or that you haven't `virtualenv.py` installed.

Comment: And below that, it says how to install it. The error is on how to install it using Sudo, not on my Python interpreter version. Python 3 works absolutely fine.

Comment: What if you go to the directory `microblog`, and then do `python -m venv flask`? I noticed you use `python3` and not `python`. Would that help?

Comment: That's because I'm using Mac OS, and python automatically does Python 2. So I need to do python3, or it'll run on Python 2